# C# MySQL timeout in handling signed numbers in schema

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a MySQL database with a signed integer column declared as:
`test_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL ;
Every time I execute MySqlDataAdapter code in my C#.NET program it will have a time-out error due to the datatype in MySQL. I am using MySQL.Data v6.3.5.0 dll file. I figured out it was the data type problem since if I declared the integer as UNSIGNED in MySQL the problem will not have the error instead it will successfully execute the command.

The problem now is I cannot have negative numbers in my database because of this error. Am I missing a fix for the MySQL dll files?

Same code is executed for both SIGNED(default) and UNSIGNED INT with different results:
**SIGNED INT**  = error (A connection attempt failed because the connected party 
              did not properly respond after a period of time, or established 
              connection failed because connected host has failed to respond)

**UNSIGNED INT**  = successful

***This is also true if columns declared as DECIMALS will have negative numbers

```
  DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

  string query = sql;

  //Open connection
  if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
  {
      MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, 
                                                          connection);
      dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

      //return list to be displayed
      return dataSet;
  }
  else
  {
     throw new Exception("Connection is closed.");
  }
```

Comment: The definition of "unsigned" is "It does not store the sign (-)" so when using unsigned data types you cannot have negative values. You seems to have problem with the database types and .net types, but you can check what those are  https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/DataTypeMapping.html

Comment: MySQL.Data v6.3.5.0 is a pretty old version; try updating to 8.0.16 or switching to MySqlConnector 0.56.0 https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/

Comment: @bradbury9 this might be the case but I could not change that part of the code since it is thrown from the DLL itself. Maybe the DLL is not really compatible to my current MySQL server which is 8.x.x.x but I got stuck with this old DLL version since it was already there working with the previous code.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger this was my first thought but I gave it a try if someone is able to figure this out using the old DLL since replacing the old DLL might also affect other parts of the program which is already using is. But I'll try to update the DLL and hopefully everything runs smooth.